# iosSlider linking to slides

Tags: jquery, hash, hyperlink, slider

I'm trying to use [iosSlider](http://www.iosscripts.com/iosslider/), but I'm unable to link to the slides.

I'm using the following function [here](http://lbtrn.com/iosSlider/_demos/_site-demo/#0) to add the current slide's number to the URL, which is working fine, but [linking](http://lbtrn.com/iosSlider/_demos/_site-demo/#3) to these always loads the first slide instead of #3, #4...

```
function slideContentChange(args) {

    window.location.href =  '#' + args.currentSlideNumber

    /* indicator (original code) */
    $('.iosSliderButtons .button').removeClass('selected');
    $('.iosSliderButtons .button:eq(' + args.currentSlideNumber + ')').addClass('selected');

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I've contacted the author of the script. This feature is not supported yet, [he's currently working on it](https://github.com/iosscripts/iosSlider/issues/98). I'll post the how-to when it is available.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in the doc ready:

```
var hash = window.location.hash || '1';
var startSlide = hash.replace("#", "");             
//alert(startSlide);

$('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
    // other init variables..
    startAtSlide: startSlide
});
```

Does this help?